# How to mint / transfer ERC1155 token to ERC6551 token bound address of ERC721 directly after mint?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, erc721, erc1155

Say I have a smart contract for an ERC721 NFT collection (a), an ERC6551 smart contract that deploys a token bound account for these NFTS (b), and a contract for ERC1155 tokens (c).

Here's what I want to accomplish:
*Upon mint the user receives 1 ERC721 NFT that has a token bound account already deployed and is pre-stacked with the ERC1155 token.*

With my little knowledge in this field I'd implement it like this:

- after mint on contract (a), call contract (b) to deploy token bound account
- once the TBA is deployed, call contract (c) to mint / transfer ERC1155 token to the TBA

Is this generally how you would implement something like that, or am I completely off?
I'd aprpeciate any conceptual hint in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your approach is correct.
But there are some areas that can be optimized, such as combining the functions of contract A and contract B together。

Comment: Yes, I already combined A and B and it's working like expected. Thanks for your input anyways!